# Table View doesn't show Data, why? (Swift 3)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, swift3, userdefaults

I've made an app using a table view to persist data. The table view shows the elements of an array which is saved through UserDefaults. Since TableViewControllers look kind of ugly, I did it a bit different: I put a TableView into a normal ViewController. 
My problem is: even though I did everything I could to get the TableView to show the data, it doesn't, and I don't know why. Could anyone help me?
Here's the code of the ViewController:

```
class ErfolgreicheChallenges: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var myTableView: UITableView!

    var data = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        myTableView.delegate = self

        data.append("test")
        data.append("lol")

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        myTableView.dataSource = self

        let cell = myTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel!.text = data[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    }

}
```

Thanks to everyone for having a look! Have a great day

Comment: It may have been a good decision to forego the UITableViewController, but using a regular VC requires a few extra steps.  The most important of which is to set the tableView's data source to the class containing the posted code.  Did you do that?

Comment: Where do you call `reloadData()` on the table view?

Comment: well, when I set the data source to self in the viewDidLoad(), I always get a 'Thread 1'-error or something, don't know what the problem is... Or do you mean something else?

Comment: Did try that but my app fails when I try to reloadData()... Where do you think do I need to call that?

Comment: Also - you're not persisting the data in a table view, you're just displaying it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `viewDidLoad` with

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    myTableView.dataSource = self
    myTableView.delegate = self

    data.append("test")
    data.append("lol")
    myTableView.reloadData()

}
```

and replace `numberOfRowsInSection` with

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }
```

and delete `myTableView.dataSource = self` in `cellForRow`.

If the code is crashing then `myTableView` is not connected in IB.

As mentioned in the comments, consider to use `UITableViewController` which got a table view instance with pre-connected data source and delegate.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using a UIViewController and embedded UITableView if you want to add other controls to the display - but you do need to connect your table view.

Comment: @Russell No, there is nothing wrong, but at the moment it looks like there is only a table view.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the data source and data delegate in viewDidLoad, or somewhere similar.

You are setting the datasource inside `cellForRowAt`, but that will never be called!

Comment: When I set the datasource to self in the viewDidLoad(), I get a 'Thread 1'-error or something... Do you know where that could come from?